# Istio: handling host redirect when hitting selective endpoints

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, istio

I have an app that has a legacy hostname and a new one. I have defined two nginx ingresses before Istio came into play, each ingress taking care of one hostname. For any traffic requesting with the legacy hostname, I want it to be redirected to the new hostname, with the exception of API, http, or non GET requests. In ingress, I could have defined something like this as a location snippet:

```
set $redir 1;
if ($request_method != GET) {
        set $redir 0;
}
if ($request_uri ~ ^/api) {
        set $redir 0;
}
if ($http_authorization) {
        set $redir 0;
}
if ($redir = 1) {
        return 301 https://{{ .redirectHost }}$request_uri;
}
```

Looking at Istio documentation, I understand I can rewrite requests if string can be matched either `prefix`, `exact`, or `regex` way but they don't meet my use case here. Any ideas on how to rewrite response?

Comment: AFAIK the options you mentioned are the only one you can use. An idea might be to use your nginx as a workaround, so the traffic would go through the istio gateway, you would specify your nginx pod with above configuration as your virtual service route host and it would be responsible for the rewrite?